# Identify 'clean' songs for radio airplay

Tags: web-crawler, keyword, airplay

I have a database of songs to review for content to see if they’re suitable for radio airplay.

Would it be possible to create a program that uses a web crawler to scan specific artists’ pages on a lyrics website (for ex. Lyrics on Demand) for specific keywords?

I could search for The Clash and the program would give me a list of all the Clash pages on the Lyrics on Demand website that contain specific "obscene" words. Since lyrics websites tend to be organized in such a way that the URLs contain actual song titles 
(For ex. http://www.lyricsondemand.com/c/theclashlyrics/rockthecasbahlyrics.html), I’d be able to look at the retrieved list and know exactly which songs were not suitable for airplay. Or, even better, the program would only search for the songs contained on the station's iTunes Music folder.

Could a program even do that? Any insight and/or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One point about your library seems to be important for me: 
The tracks have to be named in a clean way like "artist - title (remix)". If they're like: ArtistXYTrackName, you have to rename them first.

I think it should be easy to scan the library and make a list of it. 
Then I'm sure there are some lyric pages that offer an interface. 
Then you just search for every track in your tracklist -> scan the database of the lyric page -> and scan again for the keywords.

I did a little research and found a lyric database offering an interface (API). I think, I can write you a little tool for your needs.

Comment: Thanks so much for responding and for the information. I didn't know about APIs and I think I just visited the website to which you referred. When you say that I'd need to clean up the track titles, are you just saying that the songs should have their proper titles? If so, they do...I had to make sure all the songs in the library were properly categorized to help utilize the features on our DJ software (Megaseg). Or...did you mean that I'd need to rename all the tracks so that they would each include the artist and song title?

Comment: All the tracks need to be set with "artist - track name", otherwise it is not possible for any tool to tell which track is intended

Comment: But before you edit all your tracks, it would be more reasonable, to finish a tool with a couple edited tracks and see, if everything works fine.